# sp_blitz fails with: Msg 468, Level 16, State 9 Cannot resolve collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_BIN"

Tags: sql-server, collation, sp-blitz

Has anyone had an issue with running **sp_blitz** on an instance using the `Latin1_BIN` collation? I created the stored procedure without error, but when I ran it I got the following error message:

```
Msg 468, Level 16, State 9, Procedure dbo.sp_Blitz, Line 905 [Batch Start Line 9]
Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and
   "Latin1_General_BIN" in the equal to operation.
```

I then created a separate database with the `Latin1_General_CPI_CI_AS` collation, create the **sp_blitz** procedure, and this threw out more errors when executed. Probably due to the joins to the system object.

Is there an easy way to fix this or an updated script, without me having to troubleshoot and rewrite every line of code?

**sp_blitz info**

@Version = '8.03', @VersionDate = '20210420'

**collation query results**

```
InstanceCollation     SystemDbCollation     TempDbCollation
Latin1_General_BIN    Latin1_General_BIN    SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

Comment: 1) When providing further details, please use the [edit] link at the bottom of the question so the info is all in one place and not scattered between the question and 1 or more comments. 2) When updating the question, please include version of SQL Server and **sp_blitz**. 3) Please add the exact and complete error message to the question (starting with "Msg ..."). 4) Are you using contained databases?

Comment: Actually, please use the following updated query and update the question with those results: `SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('collation') AS [InstanceCollation], DATABASEPROPERTYEX(N'master', 'collation') AS [SystemDbCollation], DATABASEPROPERTYEX(N'tempdb', 'collation') AS [TempDbCollation];`. Thanks.

Comment: Hi - thx for sticking w me - I don't see "add info" but here is the output of the previous query request

Comment: There is an "edit" link, just below the tags...

Comment: are you using the latest version ? https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/blob/dev/sp_Blitz.sql .. seems like you are using old version https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/blob/dev/sp_Blitz.sql#L41 ... latest is 8.11 `SELECT @Version = '8.11', @VersionDate = '20221013'` updated to latest version and see if you get any issues ..

Answer (score 0):

The initial problem is that yes, there are several places in **sp_blitz** that compare a string column: database name. The comparison is usually (I didn't check the entire proc) between the system catalog view, `sys.databases`, and the temporary table, `#SkipChecks` in a `NOT IN` predicate:

```sql
FROM    master.sys.databases d
...
WHERE   ...
        AND d.name NOT IN ( SELECT DISTINCT
                            DatabaseName
                            FROM  #SkipChecks
...
```

#### Part 1

So, the immediate problem is that:

1. The collation of the `name` column in `sys.databases` is `Latin1_General_BIN`, which correctly reflects your instance/server -level collation, but the collation of the `DatabaseName` column in `SkipChecks` is `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` due to this being a temporary table and by default, the collation of string columns is taken from the default collation of `tempdb`, which on your system is `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`.

   ***AND***
2. The collation of the predicate is not being forced via the `COLLATE` option.

This is not a problem/error most people get because `tempdb` nearly always has the same collation as the instance/server and the other system databases (i.e. `master`, `msdb`, and `model`.

#### Part 2

That brings us to the root cause of the problem: under normal conditions, the collation of `tempdb` should *nearly* always be the same as the instance/server -level collation, as well as the other three system databases. This is handled during installation. (And, I emphasized "nearly" due to contained databases using the database's default collation for string columns in temp tables.)

Somehow your `tempdb` collation is different than the instance/server -level collation, as well as the `master` and (I assume) `msdb` databases. I suspect that the `model` database was restored from an instance configured to use `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` (since `tempdb` is rebuilt from `model` every the time instance starts up).

An easy way to confirm this is to use a modified version of the query I had you execute to get the server and `tempdb` collations (this time we will get the collation for `model`, perhaps something we should have done the first time around, as well as `msdb` just to be sure):

```sql
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('collation') AS [InstanceCollation],
       DATABASEPROPERTYEX(N'master', 'collation') AS [MasterDbCollation],
       DATABASEPROPERTYEX(N'msdb', 'collation') AS [MSDbCollation],
       DATABASEPROPERTYEX(N'model', 'collation') AS [ModelDbCollation],
       DATABASEPROPERTYEX(N'tempdb', 'collation') AS [TempDbCollation];
```

**Fix**

Hence, to fix this:

You cannot execute `ALTER DATABASE [model] COLLATE ....;` , not even when running in Single User mode, since it is a system database.

You will need to restore the `model` database from an instance configured to use `Latin1_General_BIN`. If you don't have another instance already using `Latin1_General_BIN`, then just go through the install process (on a non-production server), select the fewest options possible, and stick with all defaults *except* for the collation, which should be set to `Latin1_General_BIN`.

Comment: @HannahVernon Interesting. Thanks for looking into that. I could have sworn that you and I answered a question years ago that involved a system where it was only `tempdb` that was different. But, I don't remember it fully so maybe `model` wasn't looked into, or maybe `model` had been fixed but the instance not yet restarted. Regardless, I updated my answer based on your findings (and offered a way to check `model` directly rather than inferring from a restart). Thanks again .

Comment: No problem - when I look at my answers list there are so many I have zero recollection about lol.